# Removing gap between navbar options

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a navbar menu for my website and I am trying to figure out how to remove the gap between each of the navbar links. As far as I can tell the li attributes with the class dropdown are a few pixels wider then the rest of the link. I have been unsuccessful with trying to remove this gap.

Below is the code for the navbar dropdown menu 
(Please note that there are some link attributes that link to local bootstrap js and css files. Please adjust accordingly if you are going to copy and paste my code directly. Thank you):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>
body {
    top: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

#mainNav {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}
#mainNav .dropdown{
    display:inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.mainNavDD li{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.mainNavDD a{
    color: #524F4F;
    padding: 10px 20px 12px 20px;
    height: 100%;
}

.mainNavLink {
    border-right: 1px solid #d6d6d6;

    background: rgb(101,0,10); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(101,0,10,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 75%, rgba(101,0,10,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(101,0,10,1)), color-stop(25%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(25%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(25%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(75%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(101,0,10,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(101,0,10,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 75%,rgba(101,0,10,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(101,0,10,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 75%,rgba(101,0,10,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(101,0,10,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 75%,rgba(101,0,10,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(101,0,10,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 25%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 75%,rgba(101,0,10,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#65000a', endColorstr='#65000a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */                

}

#mainNav a:hover{
    color: #65000A;
}


ul .mainNavDD{
    padding: none;
}
.dropdown {
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: -50px;

}

#brandMenu {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #65000A;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #4F5153;
}

.dropdown-menu li a:hover{
    background-color: #65000A;
    color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0; // remove the gap so it doesn't close
}

.brandDD {
    float: right;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 200px;
}

.dropdown-menu.columns-2 {
    min-width: 400px;
}

.dropdown-menu.columns-3 {
    min-width: 600px;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.multi-column-dropdown {

}

.multi-column-dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    color: #333;
    white-space: normal;
}

.multi-column-dropdown li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #262626;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

ul .multi-column-dropdown {
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="break"></div>
    <div id="mainNav" class="marginTop hidden-xs hidden-sm" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <ul class="mainNavDD">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle mainNavLink" data-toggle="dropdown">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle mainNavLink" data-toggle="dropdown">Skin Care</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here that's extra long so we can see how it looks</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle mainNavLink" data-toggle="dropdown">Hair Care</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here that's extra long so we can see how it looks</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle mainNavLink" data-toggle="dropdown">Bath &#38; Body</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here that's extra long so we can see how it looks</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a solution for you,instead of this:

```css
#mainNav .dropdown{
    display:inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

change to this:

```css
#mainNav .dropdown{
    float:left; /* new */
    width:auto; /* new */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Not quiet sure why you need the `width:500px` on your first `li`, so I removed otherwise the `width:auto` used above has to be used with `!important` (not advised)

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/51u8L7q0/) (expand the window to see the menu)

Comment: This worked as well and worked slightly better then the -5px hack below. That is why this one is marked the answer

Comment: Glad that I could help ;)

Answer (score 1):

try css:

```
.navbar-header{
    margin: 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
}
```

Comment: I do not use navbar-header as a class anywhere. since on the actual site I have a navbar at the top of the screen and then this navigation bar is lower in the page

Comment: .navbar-header is a fake class, put the actual class there. would you like me to edit?

Comment: Ah ok. I tried your css and it doesnt seem to have any effect. The problem seems to be the dropdown class.

Answer (score 1):

Quick hack is to add a negative margin to the items.

```
#mainNav .dropdown:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: -5px;
}
```

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/OBMXztlYMv)

[image: Navbar without space]

Comment: Welcome Casper! :) Yes, dippas answer is better. You need to adjust the -5px value to your requirement though.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest fix:

```
#mainNav .dropdown {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Then in the `.dropdown` selector, remove `width: 300px;`.